# Limit TreeView/ListView item edit characters

Tags: winforms, listviewitem, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView and a list view controls that both supports edit their item nodes, but I want to limit them to 256 characters max, one way to do it, is to validate the Length of the string in the OnAfterLabelEdit, but what I want to do it make the edit box stop accepting characters when it reaches 256. same as

TextBox.Maxlength

Comment: Well, it is technically possible.  Send the TVM_GETEDITCONTROL message in the BeforeLabelEdit event to get a handle to the edit control.  Then send it EM_SETLIMITTEXT.  Pinvoke required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do that with TreeView/ListView items unlike with TextBoxes. You could either try [TVITEM structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773456.aspx) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298228/how-can-set-maxlength-for-treenode-name-and-text-property). Or you could capture the text changed event and validate...